# Uniform Limit vs. Integral Mean

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, lebesgue-integral

Denote uniform norm:
$$\|f\|:=|f(t)|_{t\in\mathbb{R}}:=\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|f(t)|$$

Consider a sequence:
$$f_n\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}):\quad\|f-f_n\|\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0$$

> Then does it hold:
>   $$\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf_n(t)\stackrel{T\to\infty}{\to}M_n\implies\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf(t)\stackrel{T\to\infty}{\to}M$$
>   I suppose this is wrong?

For readability: $M:=\lim_{n\to\infty}M_n$

Comment: What is $M_n$ ?

Comment: A convergent sequence of reals.

Comment: @Max: A hopefully convergent sequence of reals...

Comment: deleted my answer, messed things up since i didnt start with an epsilon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $n$ and $T$, we have 
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f - M \right\rvert 
&\leq 
\left\lvert \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f - \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f_n \right\rvert
+ 
\left\lvert \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f_n - M_n \right\rvert 
+ 
\left\lvert M_n - M \right\rvert \\
&\leq 
\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T \left\lvert f - f_n \right\rvert
+ 
\left\lvert \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f_n - M_n \right\rvert 
+ 
\left\lvert M_n - M \right\rvert \\
&\leq 
\lVert f-f_n\rVert_\infty
+ 
\left\lvert \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f_n - M_n \right\rvert 
+ 
\left\lvert M_n - M \right\rvert \\
\end{align}
$$

Now, fix $\varepsilon > 0$, and choose $N=N_\varepsilon$ such that for any $n\geq N$ it holds that both $\lvert M_n - M \rvert\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ and $\lVert f-f_n\rVert_\infty\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$. Then, for any $T>0$ and $n\geq N$,

$$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f - M \right\rvert 
&\leq 
\frac{\varepsilon}{3}
+ 
\left\lvert \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f_n - M_n \right\rvert 
+ 
\frac{\varepsilon}{3} \\
\end{align}
$$
Let $n^\ast\geq N_\varepsilon$ be fixed from now. 
Using the hypothesis on the convergence of $\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f_n^\ast$ (which holds for any $n$, so in particular for $n^\ast$): there exists $T_\varepsilon$ such that, for $T\geq  T_\varepsilon$,
$$
\left\lvert \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f_{n^\ast} - M_{n^\ast} \right\rvert \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{3}.
$$
Plugging it back, we have that for any $T\geq T_\varepsilon$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f - M \right\rvert 
&\leq 
\frac{\varepsilon}{3}
+ 
\frac{\varepsilon}{3} 
+ 
\frac{\varepsilon}{3}  = \varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$
This shows that indeed $\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^T f \xrightarrow[T\to\infty]{} M$.

**Edit:** as asked (and answered) in the comments, the assumption that the sequence $(M_n)_n$ converges is not necessary. Specifically, convergence of $(M_n)_n$ towards a limit $M\in\mathbb{R}$ is implied by the other hypotheses: that is, the convergence of $\lVert f- f_n\rVert_\infty$ can be used to show that $(M_n)_n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Ah true, thanks!! So that is because the first and last expression are independant of time?

Comment: Hope you don't mind: Hence you can make it even a one-liner as: $0\leq|\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf(s)\mathrm{d}s-M|\leq\|f-f_n\|_\infty+|\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T f_n(s)\mathrm{d}s-M_n|+|M-M_n|\stackrel{T\to\infty}{\to}\ldots \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0$

Comment: I think the existence for the limit of integrals might be redundant? Maybe this might be worked out too?   *(I thought about some simple constructions for counterexamples but it seems this follows by assumption.)*

Comment: Regarding the "one-liner" version: one has to be careful with these compact arguments. A lot of details are hidden by the two consecutive limits, and going back to epsilon exactly ensures that this hidden stuff works out. (If not careful, many wrong things can be "proven" by concise proofs that hide the exact quantifiers.)

Comment: By the redundancy of the limit of integrals, do you mean the fact that M_n converges (I.e., are you asking whether that's already implied by the uniform convergence of the f_n's?)

Comment: Yes that's what I mean by the redundancy: The uniform limit plus the existence of integral means implies also the convergence of integral means.

Comment: (A priori, I think so. Try to show (M_n) is Cauchy, using the fact that (f_n) is for the L_infinity norm.)

Comment: Sure one must be careful; but if one is familiar enough they turn out to be quite useful namely no epsilon-arguments.

Comment: Yeeeeesss it works too thanks!!! :D More or less the same line but starting with: $0\leq|M_m-M_n|\leq\ldots$